# How did خشاب become the Persian word for magazine?

Tags: etymology, arabic, words, persian, perso-arabic-script

In Iran magazine (in a gun) is called خشاب (*kheshab*). I tried to find a relation to another language but I failed.

The only thing I found is that خشب (*khashb*) means wood in Arabic.

In Arabic magazine is called مخزن (*makhzan*) which means reservoir (the word *magazine* itself is related to the Arabic noun).

Is خشاب in Persian related to Arabic خشب? If yes, what's the relation between gun magazine and wood?

Comment: There is _The Etymological Dictionary of the Iranian Languages_ which is being published by the Russian Academy of Sciences. The 1st volume «a—ā» was published in 2000, the latest one, the 6th one «p—r̥» in 2020, so we can see they publish a volume every 4–5 years, each one covering 2–3 letters. Your word خشاب (_kheshab_) begins with _x_ according to the notation this dictionary uses, this letter goes a way after _r̥_, which is followed by _s, ś, š, t, ϑ, u, ū, u̯_, and only then goes our _x_. This means the volume containing your word will appear there no earlier than in 15 years...

Comment: And 15 years is quite problematic a term for the Russian Academy of Sciences to continue its existence, taking into account the current situation in the world. [Here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Этимологический_словарь_иранских_языков) is what Wikipedia writes about this dictionary. Alternatively, I suggest your looking for this book: Hassandust, Mohammad. 2015. _The etymological dictionary of Persian_. 5 Vols. Tehran: Academy of Persian Language and Literature. Unfortunately, I have no access to it. I wish you good luck, your quest is quite interesting.

Comment: Dear close voters; Please add comment.